# The property does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I'm currently working on enabling drag-and-drop support for our company app. 
The error I keep getting seems weird to me. 
What this says is that

```
The property 'DragDropHelper.IsDragSource' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:DragAndDrop;assembly=DragAndDrop'. Line 61 Position 83
```

The property is an attached property in the class I found in the Internet in the samples and modified it a bit. Here is property declaration:

```
namespace DragAndDrop {
public class DragDropHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSourceProperty =    
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSource", typeof (bool), typeof (DragDropHelper),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsDragSourceChanged));

    public static bool GetIsDragSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(IsDragSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsDragSource(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsDragSourceProperty, value);
    }
```

It seems to me that attached property is completely valid, isn't it? 
This DragDropHelper is included into a class library, that I reference from the main client app.
When I try to set the value of the property in a client app:

```
 <ListView x:Uid="list" x:Name="CurrentFolderItemsControl" drag:DragDropHelper.IsDragSource="true" />
```

VS2010 says that property doesn't exist in XML namespace. The XAML document is a resource dictionary 
which is merged into main client app resources, because it contains styles for our control.
**It's even more weird because I created a class within main app that has attached property, then set property value in XAML markup - app compiled OK**

Comment: What assembly is the DragDropHelper class located in?

Comment: DragDropHelper class located in a separate class library, and I reference the library from the main client app

Comment: How did you declare the namespace in XAML ? (xmlns:drag="...")

Comment: xmlns:drag="clr-namespace:DragAndDrop;assembly=DragAndDrop"

Comment: Could you please share the full class of DragDropHelper here http://snipt.org/ and provide the link

Comment: sure, here it is http://snipt.org/lnkJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. My error was I didn't recompile the library after having added attached property. After I did so, everything works as expected. Sorry everybody :(

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the necro... just thought I'd share what happened in my similar scenario. I copied my View from an external project, which referenced the behaviour's namespace internally:

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.Behaviours"
b:WindowBehaviours.Close="{Binding ClosingView}"
```

Two things needed to happen for this to work. Firstly, the xmlns needed to explicitly reference the assembly for the behaviour class, like so:

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.Behaviours;assembly=Common"
```

Secondly, I temporarily removed the second line **and rebuilt my solution first**. VS2012 sometimes gets its knickers in a knot when you clone WPF projects, and a good Clean & Rebuild without the offending line often fixes things (it recognised the behaviour after I added the line back again).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you did. I got it to work by placing the `[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren]` attribute above my setter method. Don't ask me why, it just worked...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I defined the control (button in my case) before defining the handler. I had to delete the button and redefine it after creating the method to clear the error.